# Boltzmann's principle and choice of macrostate in an ideal paramagnet

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In an old exam, a task was given that looks at $N$ electrons with spin parallell or anti-parallell to an external magnetic field, with possible energies respectively $-\mu_bB$ and $\mu_bB$. Using the the partition function (and a formula provided for mean entropy per electron), one finds the entropy when the magnetic field is $B=0 $ to be $S=Nk_bln2$, which then shall be explained using Boltzmann's principle $S=k_BlnW$, where $W$ is the number of microstates corresponding to the macrostate.

$S=Nk_bln2$ implies that $W=2^N$, which are $\bf{all}$ the microstates. Shouldn't it be assumed that the macrostate is one where net magnetic moment is zero, and thus get something less than $2^N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the B-field is zero, all states are equally likely, there is no energy difference, all $2^N$ states have the same internal energy. There is no constraint on the magnetization. That it is $M \approx 0$ is just a consequence of the statistics of large numbers.

Comment: But if we were to measure the magnetization, and find $M=0$, this would result in an entirely different $W$, and by extension $S$, thereby changig the $S$ just by achieving additional information... I've read that entropy is information-dependent, but this seems a bit weird. Also, we go from using $W$ as #microstates corresponding to a macrostate, to summing microstates for all macrostates when it isn't specified. What's the justification for this? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ØyvindChristiansen You would be unlikely to find $M$ unequal zero only if $N$ is large. Then almost all macrostates have close to zero magnetization. The logarithm of that number will be very very close to $\ln 2$.

Comment: A friend of me actually found that this approached $ln2$, by using the binomial coefficient. Does that work in general? That when the macrostate is unspecified, you can sum all the microstates, and any specified macrostate's entropy will approach the one for the unspecified for large $N$?

Comment: @ØyvindChristiansen That depends on what you specify. If saturated magnetization is specified, that is a macrostate with only one microstate for any $N$. But indeed, large numbers can behave in unexpected ways. A sum over the whole binomial distribution gives $2^N$. For large $N$, the distribution is very strongly peaked. In the limit, it may even be enough to take just the single value $M=0$ to get a correct value of the entropy (Stirling's formula etc).